# Google Cloud AutoML predict service returned 'Internal error encountered'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, automl, google-cloud-automl

I trained a model on Google cloud vision AutoML service and whenever I try to predict an image from the console it returned 'Internal error encountered'. this is also happening from the API. it returns this json

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
```

The model has been training for 24 hours

it should return the image predicated classes as trained by the model

Comment: try via their online predictor, sometimes I notices models are not available

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a bug in AutoML, the problem is if you have a dataset that you traied a model on, say for 1 hour, the resumed training. AutoML creates a new model rather than modifying the old one. If you deleted the old one though, the new model won't work and will show the above error.